# Is it possible to use private project templates with Leiningen

Tags: clojure, amazon-s3, leiningen

We use [S3 wagon private](https://github.com/technomancy/s3-wagon-private) to host our own private Maven repo in AWS S3. I'd like to do the same with a Leiningen project template, but I haven't been able to work out how to tell Leiningen to pull the template from S3 when running `lein new <tmpl> <proj>`. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this capacity has been added to Leiningen 22 days ago.

See [issue1510](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/1510) on Leiningen's github.